# How to highlight Python syntax in LaTeX Listings \lstinputlistings command

Tags: python, syntax, listings

I am using package listings to import my Python source code into my LaTeX document. I use the command `\lstinputlistings`. I have a Python source like

```py
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        bla bla bla...
```

What should I write in my `\lstset` command in order to highlight words `MyClass`, `__init__` etc.?
I wouldn't want to write any word I want to be highlighted. I tried using `moredelims=[s][\color{teal}]{class}{(}` inside lstset but it doesn't work.

Comment: And why is `morekeywords={...}` not working with lstinputlistings. It does with lstlistings environment, but doesn't with input from a source file.

Comment: I'd recommend using `minted` instead or `pythontex`. They produce much better results and also the default highlighting is already coloured (and the colours are nice). Anyway this should really be posted in TeX Exchange as unutbu said. (On a side note: don't add information as comment, edit your question).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'd consider running your code through pygments to generate the latex, probably using the minted package. You can get some details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966425/source-code-highlighting-in-latex#1985330 .

Answer (score 146):

Good approach is defining new environments for programming language. Minimal setup can be around this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Default fixed font does not support bold face
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttb}{T1}{txtt}{bx}{n}{12} % for bold
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttm}{T1}{txtt}{m}{n}{12}  % for normal

% Custom colors
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}

\usepackage{listings}

% Python style for highlighting
\newcommand\pythonstyle{\lstset{
language=Python,
basicstyle=\ttm,
morekeywords={self},              % Add keywords here
keywordstyle=\ttb\color{deepblue},
emph={MyClass,__init__},          % Custom highlighting
emphstyle=\ttb\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
frame=tb,                         % Any extra options here
showstringspaces=false
}}


% Python environment
\lstnewenvironment{python}[1][]
{
\pythonstyle
\lstset{#1}
}
{}

% Python for external files
\newcommand\pythonexternal[2][]{{
\pythonstyle
\lstinputlisting[#1]{#2}}}

% Python for inline
\newcommand\pythoninline[1]{{\pythonstyle\lstinline!#1!}}

\begin{document}

\section{``In-text'' listing highlighting}

\begin{python}
class MyClass(Yourclass):
    def __init__(self, my, yours):
        bla = '5 1 2 3 4'
        print bla
\end{python}

\section{External listing highlighting}

\pythonexternal{demo.py}

\section{Inline highlighting}

Definition \pythoninline{class MyClass} means \dots

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: very nice, helped me a lot. My suggestion is to add \small to all styles, to make it smaller. Right now the code looks clumsy and big to me

Comment: Have to look at this more later, I implemented this but then I had lines with answers to question c) where I was putting that in Math Mode: $c)$ and this was tripping up the utf-8 encoding and some other errors, but otherwise this is awesome!! +1

Comment: This seems to not understand `"""triple quoted strings"""`. Any chance there is some wizardry to make this happen? I've been looking for things that can be passed to `\lstset`, but so far I've come up with nothing useful (only ways to change the color of strings).

Comment: Nevermind, found the incantation. It's `morestring=[s]{"""}{"""}`. Found it here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235742/156739

Comment: Any chance of getting a listing number and caption with this method?

Comment: @redmode: great answer, thx so much! ... is there a way to add a subcaption to the code? Such as: Listing 1: "my caption". ?

Comment: I asked a question about how to caption it? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/590342/143861

Answer (score 74):

I found this python package [pythonhighlight](https://github.com/olivierverdier/python-latex-highlighting) on Github

Define it like this `\usepackage{pythonhighlight}` and use it like this:

```
\begin{python}
def f(x):
    return x
\end{python}
```

Comment: Nice. The support for inline code using `\pyth{print("Hello World!")}` was really helpful!

Comment: Grand - and it is even available in Ubuntu's standard packages (`apt show texlive-science | grep python`).

Comment: very nice package ! love it !

Comment: This answers to the point. This should have been the accepted answer.

Comment: How is this not the accepted answer? Wonderful, single line change.  The right level of abstraction for the problem.  (Also, incidentally, this method produced color successfully on my end, whereas the accepted answer did not.)

Comment: Note that it is based on listings, and internally creates a style named `mypython`, so you can create derived styles directly (even if it's not documented, I just hope they wont later change the name of the environment). Practical if you want to add line numbering for instance using `\lstnewenvironment{pythonLines}[1][]{\lstset{style=mypython,numbers=left}}{}`, and then in your document `\begin{pythonLines}your python code\end{pythonLines}`

Comment: Any way to include mathematical symbols in this?

Answer (score 6):

Some while ago I have modified the existing python language-definition from the `listings`-package:

[Listings: syntax for literate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235731/listings-syntax-for-literate)

You might find something useful. If I remember correctly, one can put all this in an external `*.sty`-file. Also see the [follow-up question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235783/listings-recognize-numbers-and-1e-3).

[image: another problem]

Comment: How do you I remove the first quotation marks? Even though my code doesn't have the quotation marks. In the output PDF the quotation marks appear. I couldn't figure out what creates those quotation marks?

Comment: @nxkryptor: that was a bug that appeared, because I forgot the comma after some command. See the linked follow up; its code should have that fixed. It was mentioned in the answer of the first question though.