# Problem with listings package for Python syntax coloring

Tags: listings, syntax, python

I am implementing the method I learned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83882/how-to-highlight-python-syntax-in-latex-listings-lstinputlistings-command/83883#83883) for putting Python code in Latex. Everything works great except that I have problems with comments. Here's the code from the link I mentioned:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttb}{T1}{txtt}{bx}{n}{9} % for bold
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttm}{T1}{txtt}{m}{n}{9}  % for normal
% Defining colors
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}


\usepackage{listings}

% Python style for highlighting
\newcommand\pythonstyle{\lstset{
language=Python,
backgroundcolor=\color{white}
basicstyle=\ttm,
otherkeywords={self},            
keywordstyle=\ttb\color{deepblue},
emph={MyClass,__init__},          
emphstyle=\ttb\color{deepred},    
stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
commentstyle=\color{red}
frame=tb,                         
showstringspaces=false            
}}

% Python environment
\lstnewenvironment{python}[1][]
{
\pythonstyle
\lstset{#1}
}
{}
```

I use the following function, `python`, defined in the code, to generate `Python` code:

```
\begin{python}
 class MyClass(Yourclass):
    def __init__(self, my, yours):
        String = "String"
        String2 = '5 1 2 3 4'
        print String2
        import numpy as np #Comment1
        # Comment2
\end{python}
```

This is the result. I see two `frame` words for each comment. Do you know what can be wrong here? The link that I mentioned works perfectly in every other aspect. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have some missing comma:

```
\newcommand\pythonstyle{\lstset{
  language=Python,
  backgroundcolor=\color{white}, %%%%%%%
  basicstyle=\ttm,
  otherkeywords={self},            
  keywordstyle=\ttb\color{deepblue},
  emph={MyClass,__init__},          
  emphstyle=\ttb\color{deepred},    
  stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
  commentstyle=\color{red},  %%%%%%%%
  frame=tb,                         
  showstringspaces=false            
}}
```

Comment: Great! It solved the problem. Interestingly enough, the two lines with missing `,`, were the only lines I had added from somewhere else!