# Listings: syntax for literate

Tags: listings, optional-arguments, literate-programming

In the [documentation](http://mirror.selfnet.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf#subsection.5.4) for the [listings package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) it says:

> `literate = [*]<replacement item>. . .<replacement item>`
>
> First note that there are no commas between the items. Each item
>   consists of three arguments: `{<replace>}{<replacement text>}{<length>}`. `<replace>` is the original character sequence.
>   Instead of printing these characters, we use `<replacement text>`,
>   which takes the width of `<length>` characters in the output.
>
> [...]
>
> The optional star indicates that literate replacements should not be
>   made in strings, comments, and other delimited text.

## Problem:

I want to define my own language with `listings` but can not use the above mentioned star, as it gives me a compiling error.
The following (I tried `[]` brackets too) does not work even though it works without the star `*`:

```
literate = *{-}{{{\color{purple}-}}}{1}
```

Please note that this is just a excerpt of a bigger list of literates, which shouldn't change the usage however.

---

## MWE:

This is probably not minimal, but I wanted to keep it as close to the original as possible so one could see other errors. It is actually compiling now. It has lost its colors in the non-comment parts though, moreover it puts completely arbitrary quotation marks (this also occurs in the original).
(original [Python](http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/listings/lstdrvrs.pdf#subsection.2.65)&
[special characters](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings))

```
%Minimal
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{maroon}{cmyk}{0, 0.87, 0.68, 0.32}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}
\definecolor{ipython_frame}{RGB}{207, 207, 207}
\definecolor{ipython_bg}{RGB}{247, 247, 247}
\definecolor{ipython_red}{RGB}{186, 33, 33}
\definecolor{ipython_green}{RGB}{0, 128, 0}
\definecolor{ipython_cyan}{RGB}{64, 128, 128}
\definecolor{ipython_purple}{RGB}{170, 34, 255}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    breaklines=true,
    %
    extendedchars=true,
    literate=
    {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
    {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
    {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
    {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
    {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
    {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
    {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1
}

%%
%% Python definition (c) 1998 Michael Weber
%% Additional definitions (2013) Alexis Dimitriadis
%% modified by me (should not have empty lines)
%%
\lstdefinelanguage{iPython}{
    morekeywords={access,and,break,class,continue,def,del,elif,else,except,exec,finally,for,from,global,if,import,in,is,lambda,not,or,pass,print,raise,return,try,while},%
    %
    % Built-ins
    morekeywords=[2]{abs,all,any,basestring,bin,bool,bytearray,callable,chr,classmethod,cmp,compile,complex,delattr,dict,dir,divmod,enumerate,eval,execfile,file,filter,float,format,frozenset,getattr,globals,hasattr,hash,help,hex,id,input,int,isinstance,issubclass,iter,len,list,locals,long,map,max,memoryview,min,next,object,oct,open,ord,pow,property,range,raw_input,reduce,reload,repr,reversed,round,set,setattr,slice,sorted,staticmethod,str,sum,super,tuple,type,unichr,unicode,vars,xrange,zip,apply,buffer,coerce,intern},%
    %
    sensitive=true,%
    morecomment=[l]\#,%
    morestring=[b]',%
    morestring=[b]",%
    %
    morestring=[s]{'''}{'''},% used for documentation text (mulitiline strings)
    morestring=[s]{"""}{"""},% added by Philipp Matthias Hahn
    %
    morestring=[s]{r'}{'},% `raw' strings
    morestring=[s]{r"}{"},%
    morestring=[s]{r'''}{'''},%
    morestring=[s]{r"""}{"""},%
    morestring=[s]{u'}{'},% unicode strings
    morestring=[s]{u"}{"},%
    morestring=[s]{u'''}{'''},%
    morestring=[s]{u"""}{"""}%
    %
    % {replace}{replacement}{lenght of replace}
    % *{-}{-}{1} will not replace in comments and so on
    literate=
    {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
    {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
    {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
    {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
    {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
    {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
    {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1
    %
    {^}{{{\color{ipython_purple}\^{}}}}1
    {=}{{{\color{ipython_purple}=}}}1
    %
    {+}{{{\color{ipython_purple}+}}}1
    *{-}{{{\color{ipython_purple}-}}}1
    {*}{{{\color{ipython_purple}$^\ast$}}}1
    {/}{{{\color{ipython_purple}/}}}1
    %
    {+=}{{{+=}}}1
    {-=}{{{-=}}}1
    {*=}{{{$^\ast$=}}}1
    {/=}{{{/=}}}1,
    %
    identifierstyle=\color{black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{ipython_cyan}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{ipython_red}\ttfamily,
    keepspaces=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    %
    rulecolor=\color{ipython_frame},
    frame=single,
    frameround={t}{t}{t}{t},
    framexleftmargin=6mm,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{halfgray},
    %
    %
    backgroundcolor=\color{ipython_bg},
    %   extendedchars=true,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize,
    keywordstyle=\color{ipython_green}\ttfamily,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=iPython]
<- #there shouldn't be quotation marks
"""
---------
sin2_theta  = np.sin(theta)**2 - a + b
"""
import math
import numpy as np
from lib.analytical import csa

MAS = math.degrees(math.acos(math.sqrt(1/3)))/360 * 2* math.pi + a -b
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

---

**new question**
outsourced: [Listings: recognize numbers and `1e-3`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235783/listings-recognize-numbers-and-1e-3)

Comment: It works for me with simple code. Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: added MWE and result image.

Comment: BTW: Nice `listings` setup :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! What is so special about it? - I will update it with some more operators. (And another question: concerning `1e-3` expressions)

Comment: 'Another question' should be another question ;). This site works best when you have one question per, well, per question. You can link to this one for background information if that's appropriate.

Comment: Do the non-`*` and `*`ed literates have be in a special order ? I moved the language definition to a .sty file; [] first -> colors/errors with special characters `ö ä ü`.; [`*`] first -> no colors for operators/no errors ...

Comment: How do you get the corners of the background color to round? In my case the backgroundcolor does not follow the rounding of the frame.

Comment: @Breno That must be an error. I just used the depicted code.

Comment: @BadAtLaTeXProgramming Just tested the depicted code, the edges of the background color do not round. If it's an error here, then it might have something to do with Adobe Acrobat? I am using Windows, MikTeX 4.5. According to MikTeX, all packages are up to date.

Comment: @Breno I just checked the code (without recompiling it tbh, as I had the pdf) and there is nothing else to it. Also had a look at the [documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings?lang=de) version `1.8d` and `frameround=...` still exists. I am sorry but I can not help with that.

Comment: @BadAtLaTeXProgramming Yeah, I couldn't find anything in the docs as well. No problem. Using `frameround` here (i.e. in my PC) only rounds the frame contour, not the background color. Could you write your OS and which TeX distribution you use, please?

Comment: @Breno, a fork of [this docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/thomasweise/docker-texlive-full/). But the vanilla image should not differ for this MWE.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use a different `literate` for starred ones:

```
literate=
*{-}{{{\color{ipython_purple}-}}}1,
```

If you add more literates after this one (without the star) they will behave as if they were starred. For example

```
literate=
*{-}{{{\color{ipython_purple}-}}}1
 {?}{{{\color{ipython_purple}?}}}1,
```

Also, the quotes at the beginning of the listing are due to the fact that there's a missing comma after

```
morestring=[s]{u"""}{"""}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{maroon}{cmyk}{0, 0.87, 0.68, 0.32}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}
\definecolor{ipython_frame}{RGB}{207, 207, 207}
\definecolor{ipython_bg}{RGB}{247, 247, 247}
\definecolor{ipython_red}{RGB}{186, 33, 33}
\definecolor{ipython_green}{RGB}{0, 128, 0}
\definecolor{ipython_cyan}{RGB}{64, 128, 128}
\definecolor{ipython_purple}{RGB}{170, 34, 255}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    breaklines=true,
    %
    extendedchars=true,
    literate=
    {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
    {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
    {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
    {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
    {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
    {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
    {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1
}

%%
%% Python definition (c) 1998 Michael Weber
%% Additional definitions (2013) Alexis Dimitriadis
%% modified by me (should not have empty lines)
%%
\lstdefinelanguage{iPython}{
    morekeywords={access,and,break,class,continue,def,del,elif,else,except,exec,finally,for,from,global,if,import,in,is,lambda,not,or,pass,print,raise,return,try,while},%
    %
    % Built-ins
    morekeywords=[2]{abs,all,any,basestring,bin,bool,bytearray,callable,chr,classmethod,cmp,compile,complex,delattr,dict,dir,divmod,enumerate,eval,execfile,file,filter,float,format,frozenset,getattr,globals,hasattr,hash,help,hex,id,input,int,isinstance,issubclass,iter,len,list,locals,long,map,max,memoryview,min,next,object,oct,open,ord,pow,property,range,raw_input,reduce,reload,repr,reversed,round,set,setattr,slice,sorted,staticmethod,str,sum,super,tuple,type,unichr,unicode,vars,xrange,zip,apply,buffer,coerce,intern},%
    %
    sensitive=true,%
    morecomment=[l]\#,%
    morestring=[b]',%
    morestring=[b]",%
    %
    morestring=[s]{'''}{'''},% used for documentation text (mulitiline strings)
    morestring=[s]{"""}{"""},% added by Philipp Matthias Hahn
    %
    morestring=[s]{r'}{'},% `raw' strings
    morestring=[s]{r"}{"},%
    morestring=[s]{r'''}{'''},%
    morestring=[s]{r"""}{"""},%
    morestring=[s]{u'}{'},% unicode strings
    morestring=[s]{u"}{"},%
    morestring=[s]{u'''}{'''},%
    morestring=[s]{u"""}{"""},%
    %
    % {replace}{replacement}{lenght of replace}
    % *{-}{-}{1} will not replace in comments and so on
    literate=
    {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
    {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
    {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
    {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
    {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
    {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
    {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1
    %
    {^}{{{\color{ipython_purple}\^{}}}}1
    {=}{{{\color{ipython_purple}=}}}1
    %
    {+}{{{\color{ipython_purple}+}}}1
    {*}{{{\color{ipython_purple}$^\ast$}}}1
    {/}{{{\color{ipython_purple}/}}}1
    %
    {+=}{{{+=}}}1
    {-=}{{{-=}}}1
    {*=}{{{$^\ast$=}}}1
    {/=}{{{/=}}}1,
    literate=
    *{-}{{{\color{ipython_purple}-}}}1
     {?}{{{\color{ipython_purple}?}}}1,
    %
    identifierstyle=\color{black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{ipython_cyan}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{ipython_red}\ttfamily,
    keepspaces=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    %
    rulecolor=\color{ipython_frame},
    frame=single,
    frameround={t}{t}{t}{t},
    framexleftmargin=6mm,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{halfgray},
    %
    %
    backgroundcolor=\color{ipython_bg},
    %   extendedchars=true,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize,
    keywordstyle=\color{ipython_green}\ttfamily,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=iPython]
<- #there shouldn't be quotation marks
"""
---------
sin2_theta  = np.sin(theta)**2 - a + b ?
"""
import math
import numpy as np
from lib.analytical import csa

MAS = math.degrees(math.acos(math.sqrt(1/3)))/360 * 2* math.pi + a -b ?
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Note that I've added two `?` in your listing just to show the effect, remove them as well as `{?}{{{\color{ipython_purple}?}}}1` in the second `literate`.

Comment: Thanks! You were absolutely right to add `?`, actually even more are necessary.

Comment: @hillbilly You're welcome.

Comment: Not quite sure, if someone will read this, but I tried this and when specifying a new `literate` (for the starred ones), the old literate is gone (therefore if I take your mwe above, and add some `ä` to the source code, it will not compile since the literate conversion to `\"a` is not done anymore :/

Comment: You have made life so much more beautiful for me with this answer. Thanks a lot

Comment: I suggest modifying such that `basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily` so that the numeric characters are in the same font as the rest of the text.  You may also want to `\usepackage{upquote}` to get normal single-quotes instead of curly quotes in the output.

Comment: How do you get the corners of the background color to round? In my case the backgroundcolor does not follow the rounding of the frame.

Comment: Can the font less wider?