# Listings: recognize numbers and `1e-3`

Tags: listings

This is a follow up question. Have a look at this one:
[Listings: syntax for literate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235731/listings-syntax-for-literate)

---

*with the solution by karlkoeller*

```
%Minimal
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}
\definecolor{ipython_frame}{RGB}{207, 207, 207}
\definecolor{ipython_bg}{RGB}{247, 247, 247}
\definecolor{ipython_red}{RGB}{186, 33, 33}
\definecolor{ipython_green}{RGB}{0, 128, 0}
\definecolor{ipython_cyan}{RGB}{64, 128, 128}
\definecolor{ipython_purple}{RGB}{170, 34, 255}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    breaklines=true,
    %
    extendedchars=true,
    literate=
    {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
    {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
    {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
    {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
    {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
    {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
    {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1
}

%%
%% Python definition (c) 1998 Michael Weber
%% Additional definitions (2013) Alexis Dimitriadis
%% modified by me (should not have empty lines)
%%
\lstdefinelanguage{iPython}{
    morekeywords={access,and,break,class,continue,def,del,elif,else,except,exec,finally,for,from,global,if,import,in,is,lambda,not,or,pass,print,raise,return,try,while},%
    %
    % Built-ins
    morekeywords=[2]{abs,all,any,basestring,bin,bool,bytearray,callable,chr,classmethod,cmp,compile,complex,delattr,dict,dir,divmod,enumerate,eval,execfile,file,filter,float,format,frozenset,getattr,globals,hasattr,hash,help,hex,id,input,int,isinstance,issubclass,iter,len,list,locals,long,map,max,memoryview,min,next,object,oct,open,ord,pow,property,range,raw_input,reduce,reload,repr,reversed,round,set,setattr,slice,sorted,staticmethod,str,sum,super,tuple,type,unichr,unicode,vars,xrange,zip,apply,buffer,coerce,intern},%
    %
    sensitive=true,%
    morecomment=[l]\#,%
    morestring=[b]',%
    morestring=[b]",%
    %
    morestring=[s]{'''}{'''},% used for documentation text (mulitiline strings)
    morestring=[s]{"""}{"""},% added by Philipp Matthias Hahn
    %
    morestring=[s]{r'}{'},% `raw' strings
    morestring=[s]{r"}{"},%
    morestring=[s]{r'''}{'''},%
    morestring=[s]{r"""}{"""},%
    morestring=[s]{u'}{'},% unicode strings
    morestring=[s]{u"}{"},%
    morestring=[s]{u'''}{'''},%
    morestring=[s]{u"""}{"""},%
    %
    % {replace}{replacement}{lenght of replace}
    % *{-}{-}{1} will not replace in comments and so on
    literate=
    *{+}{{{\color{ipython_purple}+}}}1
    {-}{{{\color{ipython_purple}-}}}1
    {*}{{{\color{ipython_purple}$^\ast$}}}1
    {/}{{{\color{ipython_purple}/}}}1
    {^}{{{\color{ipython_purple}\^{}}}}1
    {?}{{{\color{ipython_purple}?}}}1
    {!}{{{\color{ipython_purple}!}}}1
    {\%}{{{\color{ipython_purple}\%}}}1
    {<}{{{\color{ipython_purple}<}}}1
    {>}{{{\color{ipython_purple}>}}}1
    {|}{{{\color{ipython_purple}|}}}1
    {\&}{{{\color{ipython_purple}\&}}}1
    {~}{{{\color{ipython_purple}~}}}1
    %
    {==}{{{\color{ipython_purple}==}}}2
    {<=}{{{\color{ipython_purple}<=}}}2
    {>=}{{{\color{ipython_purple}>=}}}2
    %
    {+=}{{{+=}}}2
    {-=}{{{-=}}}2
    {*=}{{{$^\ast$=}}}2
    {/=}{{{/=}}}2,
    %
    literate=
    {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
    {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
    {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
    {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
    {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
    {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
    {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1,
    %
%   identifierstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{ipython_cyan}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{ipython_red}\ttfamily,
    keepspaces=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    %
    rulecolor=\color{ipython_frame},
    frame=single,
    frameround={t}{t}{t}{t},
    framexleftmargin=6mm,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{halfgray},
    %
    %
    backgroundcolor=\color{ipython_bg},
    %   extendedchars=true,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{ipython_green}\ttfamily,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=iPython]
<- #there shouldn't be quotation marks
"""
---------
sin2_theta  = np.sin(theta)**2
"""
import math
import numpy as np
from lib.analytical import csa

sin2_theta  = np.sin(theta)**2
+= -= *= /= + - * / ? < > & % == <=
# += -= *= /= + - * / ? < > & % == <=
def test(a=100, b=True):
    <= >= == 2 + 3j * 7e-3
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

This yields a very nice result already :
[image: another problem]

Nevertheless numbers and `1e-3` expressions should be displayed green! The only thing concerning numbers in the documentation seems to be the line numbers section. **How do I recognize and treat them separately if they are not part of a variable name?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`listings` is not able to recognize if a number is a part of your variables or not.

What I suggest is to define a character with no meaning as an escape character (e.g. ¢) and add

```
escapechar=\¢,escapebegin=\color{ipython_green}
```

to your settings. Then use things like `¢7e-3¢` inside your listing.

MWE:

```
%Minimal
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{maroon}{cmyk}{0, 0.87, 0.68, 0.32}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}
\definecolor{ipython_frame}{RGB}{207, 207, 207}
\definecolor{ipython_bg}{RGB}{247, 247, 247}
\definecolor{ipython_red}{RGB}{186, 33, 33}
\definecolor{ipython_green}{RGB}{0, 128, 0}
\definecolor{ipython_cyan}{RGB}{64, 128, 128}
\definecolor{ipython_purple}{RGB}{170, 34, 255}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    breaklines=true,
    %
    extendedchars=true,
    literate=
    {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
    {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
    {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
    {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
    {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
    {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
    {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1
}

%%
%% Python definition (c) 1998 Michael Weber
%% Additional definitions (2013) Alexis Dimitriadis
%% modified by me (should not have empty lines)
%%
\lstdefinelanguage{iPython}{
    morekeywords={access,and,break,class,continue,def,del,elif,else,except,exec,finally,for,from,global,if,import,in,is,lambda,not,or,pass,print,raise,return,try,while},%
    %
    % Built-ins
    morekeywords=[2]{abs,all,any,basestring,bin,bool,bytearray,callable,chr,classmethod,cmp,compile,complex,delattr,dict,dir,divmod,enumerate,eval,execfile,file,filter,float,format,frozenset,getattr,globals,hasattr,hash,help,hex,id,input,int,isinstance,issubclass,iter,len,list,locals,long,map,max,memoryview,min,next,object,oct,open,ord,pow,property,range,raw_input,reduce,reload,repr,reversed,round,set,setattr,slice,sorted,staticmethod,str,sum,super,tuple,type,unichr,unicode,vars,xrange,zip,apply,buffer,coerce,intern},%
    %
    sensitive=true,%
    morecomment=[l]\#,%
    morestring=[b]',%
    morestring=[b]",%
    %
    morestring=[s]{'''}{'''},% used for documentation text (mulitiline strings)
    morestring=[s]{"""}{"""},% added by Philipp Matthias Hahn
    %
    morestring=[s]{r'}{'},% `raw' strings
    morestring=[s]{r"}{"},%
    morestring=[s]{r'''}{'''},%
    morestring=[s]{r"""}{"""},%
    morestring=[s]{u'}{'},% unicode strings
    morestring=[s]{u"}{"},%
    morestring=[s]{u'''}{'''},%
    morestring=[s]{u"""}{"""},%
    %
    % {replace}{replacement}{lenght of replace}
    % *{-}{-}{1} will not replace in comments and so on
    literate=
    {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
    {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
    {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
    {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
    {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
    {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
    {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1,
    %
    literate=
    *{+}{{{\color{ipython_purple}+}}}1
    {-}{{{\color{ipython_purple}-}}}1
    {*}{{{\color{ipython_purple}$^\ast$}}}1
    {/}{{{\color{ipython_purple}/}}}1
    {^}{{{\color{ipython_purple}\^{}}}}1
    {?}{{{\color{ipython_purple}?}}}1
    {!}{{{\color{ipython_purple}!}}}1
    {\%}{{{\color{ipython_purple}\%}}}1
    {<}{{{\color{ipython_purple}<}}}1
    {>}{{{\color{ipython_purple}>}}}1
    {|}{{{\color{ipython_purple}|}}}1
    {\&}{{{\color{ipython_purple}\&}}}1
    {~}{{{\color{ipython_purple}~}}}1
    %
    {==}{{{\color{ipython_purple}==}}}2
    {<=}{{{\color{ipython_purple}<=}}}2
    {>=}{{{\color{ipython_purple}>=}}}2
    %
    {+=}{{{+=}}}2
    {-=}{{{-=}}}2
    {*=}{{{$^\ast$=}}}2
    {/=}{{{/=}}}2,
    %
%   identifierstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{ipython_cyan}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{ipython_red}\ttfamily,
    keepspaces=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    %
    rulecolor=\color{ipython_frame},
    frame=single,
    frameround={t}{t}{t}{t},
    framexleftmargin=6mm,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{halfgray},
    %
    %
    backgroundcolor=\color{ipython_bg},
    %   extendedchars=true,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{ipython_green}\ttfamily,
    escapechar=\¢,escapebegin=\color{ipython_green},
}


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=iPython]
<- #there shouldn't be quotation marks
"""
---------
sin2_theta  = np.sin(theta)**2
"""
import math
import numpy as np
from lib.analytical import csa

sin2_theta  = np.sin(theta)**2
+= -= *= /= + - * / ? < > & % == <=
# += -= *= /= + - * / ? < > & % == <=
def test(a=¢100¢, b=True)
    <= >= == ¢2¢ + ¢3j¢ * ¢7e-3¢
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That there is only a workaround, is disappinting however (as you could change the color of all identifiers). I just added `{e+}{{{e+}}}2 {e-}{{{e-}}}2 ` to avoid the colored operator and won't dig into the code. In the end it shouldn't slow the process down even more.

Comment: Can the font size be smaller where space between characters smaller?