# Select Color of numbers if a number is directly next to letter in \lstdefinelanguage

Tags: color, listings, python

I am trying to reproduce python code in a latex report and stumbled upon some very helpful code ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235731/listings-syntax-for-literate)) to select the right colors and formatting, however, it did not include the color of numbers. I edited it in the second literate to include purple numbers and operators using the code below

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{maroon}{cmyk}{0, 0.87, 0.68, 0.32}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}
\definecolor{ipython_frame}{RGB}{207, 207, 207}
\definecolor{ipython_bg}{RGB}{247, 247, 247}
\definecolor{ipython_red}{RGB}{186, 33, 33}
\definecolor{ipython_green}{RGB}{0, 128, 0}
\definecolor{ipython_cyan}{RGB}{64, 128, 128}
\definecolor{ipython_purple}{RGB}{170, 34, 255}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{    
    %
    breaklines=true,
    %
    extendedchars=true,
    literate=
    {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
    {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
    {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
    {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
    {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
    {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
    {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1
}

%%
%% Python definition (c) 1998 Michael Weber
%% Additional definitions (2013) Alexis Dimitriadis
%% modified by me (should not have empty lines)
%%
\lstdefinelanguage{iPython}{
    morekeywords={access,and,break,class,continue,def,del,elif,else,except,exec,finally,for,from,global,if,import,in,is,lambda,not,or,pass,print,raise,return,try,while,True,False,len},%
    %
    % Built-ins
    morekeywords=[2]{abs,all,any,basestring,bin,bool,bytearray,callable,chr,classmethod,cmp,compile,complex,delattr,dict,dir,divmod,enumerate,eval,execfile,file,filter,float,format,frozenset,getattr,globals,hasattr,hash,help,hex,id,input,int,isinstance,issubclass,iter,len,list,locals,long,map,max,memoryview,min,next,object,oct,open,ord,pow,property,range,raw_input,reduce,reload,repr,reversed,set,setattr,slice,sorted,staticmethod,str,sum,super,tuple,type,unichr,unicode,vars,xrange,zip,apply,buffer,coerce,intern},%
    %
    sensitive=true,%
    %
    morecomment=[l]\#,%
    morestring=[b]',%
    morestring=[b]",%
    %
    morestring=[s]{'''}{'''},% used for documentation text (mulitiline strings)
    morestring=[s]{"""}{"""},% added by Philipp Matthias Hahn
    %
    morestring=[s]{r'}{'},% `raw' strings
    morestring=[s]{r"}{"},%
    morestring=[s]{r'''}{'''},%
    morestring=[s]{r"""}{"""},%
    morestring=[s]{u'}{'},% unicode strings
    morestring=[s]{u"}{"},%
    morestring=[s]{u'''}{'''},%
    morestring=[s]{u"""}{"""},%
    %
    % {replace}{replacement}{lenght of replace}
    % *{-}{-}{1} will not replace in comments and so on
    literate=
    {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
    {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
    {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
    {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
    {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
    {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
    {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1,
    %
    literate=*
    {=}{{{\color{ipython_purple}$=${}}}}1
    {+}{{{\color{ipython_purple}$+${}}}}1
    {-}{{{\color{ipython_purple}$-${}}}}1
    {/}{{{\color{ipython_purple}$/${}}}}1
    {?}{{{\color{ipython_purple}?{}}}}1
    {\%}{{{\color{ipython_purple}\%{}}}}1
    {*}{{{\color{ipython_purple}$^*${}}}}1
    {+=}{{{\color{ipython_purple}+={}}}}1
    {-=}{{{\color{ipython_purple}$-=${}}}}1
    {*=}{{{\color{ipython_purple}$^*=${}}}}1
    {/=}{{{\color{ipython_purple}$/=${}}}}1
    {0}{{{\color{ipython_purple}0{}}}}1
    {1}{{{\color{ipython_purple}1{}}}}1 
    {2}{{{\color{ipython_purple}2{}}}}1 
    {3}{{{\color{ipython_purple}3{}}}}1 
    {4}{{{\color{ipython_purple}4{}}}}1
    {5}{{{\color{ipython_purple}5{}}}}1 
    {6}{{{\color{ipython_purple}6{}}}}1 
    {7}{{{\color{ipython_purple}7{}}}}1 
    {8}{{{\color{ipython_purple}8{}}}}1
    {9}{{{\color{ipython_purple}9{}}}}1
    {.}{{{\color{ipython_purple}.{}}}}1
    {e-}{{{\color{ipython_purple}e-{}}}}1,
    %
    identifierstyle=\color{black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{ipython_cyan}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{ipython_red}\ttfamily,
    keepspaces=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    %
    rulecolor=\color{ipython_frame},
    frame=single,
    frameround={t}{t}{t}{t},
    framexleftmargin=6mm,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{halfgray},
    %
    %
    backgroundcolor=\color{ipython_bg},
    %   extendedchars=true,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize,
    keywordstyle=\color{ipython_green}\ttfamily,
}
```

However, now all numbers were purple which leads to some confusion when numbers are defined in a variable, e.g.

[image]

**So my question is**: is it possible to define the numbers inside a variable such that they remain black?

I think the simplest option would be:

```
if number is next to at least one black character:
    make it black
```

Because all numbers that should be purple should be surrounded by purple operations.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  All the numbers are now in the regular text font.  Shouldn't they be in the monospace font?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listings: color numbers only out of keywords](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/217505/listings-color-numbers-only-out-of-keywords)

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes you are correct, I have not attended to that yet.

Comment: @siracusa That solution may solve this, I will try it and update this when I know. Thanks