# Can we use specific packages for some parts of the LaTeX document, or how can we handle possible interference between English and Persian Styling?

Tags: code, python, xepersian, persian

I am trying to build my Ph.D thesis in a template which has been basically set for Persian language. The template is wonderful when everything is persian. But there is a problem. I need to add my `Python` code to the appendices. I found a link here in [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235731/listings-syntax-for-literate) which makes it exactly like in the `Jupyter` environment and it is beautiful.

But when I add this styling to my file, some parts of the output LaTeX file get disrupted.

The main LaTeX code is:

```
\documentclass[oneside,phd,12pt]{AUTthesis}

\usepackage{graphicx,adjustbox}
\graphicspath{{figures/}} %Setting the graphicspath
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}
\definecolor{findOptimalPartition}{HTML}{D7191C}
\definecolor{storeClusterComponent}{HTML}{FDAE61}
\definecolor{dbscan}{HTML}{ABDDA4}
\definecolor{constructCluster}{HTML}{2B83BA}


\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[skip=0pt]{caption}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand{\hlgreen}[1]{{\sethlcolor{green}\hl{#1}}}

%%%%%For colorful Jupyter style of Python code
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{maroon}{cmyk}{0, 0.87, 0.68, 0.32}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}
\definecolor{ipython_frame}{RGB}{207, 207, 207}
\definecolor{ipython_bg}{RGB}{247, 247, 247}
\definecolor{ipython_red}{RGB}{186, 33, 33}
\definecolor{ipython_green}{RGB}{0, 128, 0}
\definecolor{ipython_cyan}{RGB}{64, 128, 128}
\definecolor{ipython_purple}{RGB}{170, 34, 255}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    breaklines=true,
    %
    extendedchars=true,
    literate=
    {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
    {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
    {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
    {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
    {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
    {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
    {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1
}

%%
%% Python definition (c) 1998 Michael Weber
%% Additional definitions (2013) Alexis Dimitriadis
%% modified by me (should not have empty lines)
%%
\lstdefinelanguage{iPython}{
    morekeywords={access,and,break,class,continue,def,del,elif,else,except,exec,finally,for,from,global,if,import,in,is,lambda,not,or,pass,print,raise,return,try,while},%
    %
    % Built-ins
    morekeywords=[2]{abs,all,any,basestring,bin,bool,bytearray,callable,chr,classmethod,cmp,compile,complex,delattr,dict,dir,divmod,enumerate,eval,execfile,file,filter,float,format,frozenset,getattr,globals,hasattr,hash,help,hex,id,input,int,isinstance,issubclass,iter,len,list,locals,long,map,max,memoryview,min,next,object,oct,open,ord,pow,property,range,raw_input,reduce,reload,repr,reversed,round,set,setattr,slice,sorted,staticmethod,str,sum,super,tuple,type,unichr,unicode,vars,xrange,zip,apply,buffer,coerce,intern},%
    %
    sensitive=true,%
    morecomment=[l]\#,%
    morestring=[b]',%
    morestring=[b]",%
    %
    morestring=[s]{'''}{'''},% used for documentation text (mulitiline strings)
    morestring=[s]{"""}{"""},% added by Philipp Matthias Hahn
    %
    morestring=[s]{r'}{'},% `raw' strings
    morestring=[s]{r"}{"},%
    morestring=[s]{r'''}{'''},%
    morestring=[s]{r"""}{"""},%
    morestring=[s]{u'}{'},% unicode strings
    morestring=[s]{u"}{"},%
    morestring=[s]{u'''}{'''},%
    morestring=[s]{u"""}{"""},%
    %
    % {replace}{replacement}{lenght of replace}
    % *{-}{-}{1} will not replace in comments and so on
    literate=
    {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
    {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
    {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
    {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
    {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
    {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
    {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1
    %
    {^}{{{\color{ipython_purple}\^{}}}}1
    {=}{{{\color{ipython_purple}=}}}1
    %
    {+}{{{\color{ipython_purple}+}}}1
    {*}{{{\color{ipython_purple}$^\ast$}}}1
    {/}{{{\color{ipython_purple}/}}}1
    %
    {+=}{{{+=}}}1
    {-=}{{{-=}}}1
    {*=}{{{$^\ast$=}}}1
    {/=}{{{/=}}}1,
    literate=
    *{-}{{{\color{ipython_purple}-}}}1
     {?}{{{\color{ipython_purple}?}}}1,
    %
    identifierstyle=\color{black}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{ipython_cyan}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{ipython_red}\ttfamily,
    keepspaces=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    %
    rulecolor=\color{ipython_frame},
    frame=single,
    frameround={t}{t}{t}{t},
    framexleftmargin=6mm,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{halfgray},
    %
    %
    backgroundcolor=\color{ipython_bg},
    %   extendedchars=true,
    basicstyle=\scriptsize,
    keywordstyle=\color{ipython_green}\ttfamily,
}

\input{commands}

\begin{document}
\baselineskip=.75cm
\linespread{1.75}
\input{fa_title}
\pagenumbering{alph}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

\input{TOC-TOF-LOT}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{style1}


%--------------------------------------------------------------------------appendix

\chapterfont{\vspace*{-2em}\centering\LARGE}%

\appendix
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\include{appendix1}

\end{document}
```

And the appendix is:

```
\chapter{کد شبیه‌سازی به زبان $Python$ در بستر $Jupyter$\ref{sec5}}\label{PythonCode}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=iPython]
"""
Initial definitions
"""

KSstrategies=['S','N']
CAstrategies=['R','O','D']
ALLstrategies=['SR','SO','SD','NR','NO','ND']
ALLstrategiesCodes={'SR':0,'SO':1,'SD':2,'NR':3,'NO':4,'ND':5}
Theta = 0.2
s = 0.3333
Lambda = 0.4
Etha = 1.15
l = {'Ent':0.08,'Inc':0.08} #[Ent,Inc]
k = {'Ent':Etha*l['Ent'],'Inc':Etha*l['Inc']} #[Ent,Inc]
n={'Ent':0.27,'Inc':0.12} #[Ent,Inc]
r={'Ent':0.2,'Inc':0.15} #[Ent,Inc]
v={'Ent':0.36,'Inc':0.225} #[Ent,Inc]
rho = {'Ent':1.2,'Inc':0.8} #[Ent,Inc]
omega = {'Ent':0.9,'Inc':1.1} #[Ent,Inc]
delta = {'Ent':1.4,'Inc':0.6} #[Ent,Inc]
phi = {'Ent':0.07,'Inc':0.085} #[Ent,Inc]
tau = {'Ent':0.06,'Inc':0.066} #[Ent,Inc]
c={}
c['Inc']={'R':0.09,'O':0.10,'D':0.20} #c[R,O,D]
c['Ent']={'R':0.11,'O':0.12,'D':0.14} #c[R,O,D]
costToQualityRatio = 2
ksnoise = 0.15

"""
Define functions
"""

import numpy as np
def optimumprofitIncLead(qEnt,qInc,Leader):
    if Leader == 'Incumbent':
        #The Incumbent is the leader in pricing
        if qEnt>qInc:
            priceInc = ((qEnt - qInc)*qInc)/(2*(2*qEnt - qInc))
            profitInc = ((qEnt - qInc)*qInc)/(16*qEnt - 8*qInc)
            priceEnt = ((qEnt - qInc)*(4*qEnt - qInc))/(4*(2*qEnt - qInc))
            profitEnt = ((qEnt - qInc)*(-4*qEnt + qInc)**2)/(16*(-2*qEnt + qInc)**2)
        elif qEnt==qInc:
            priceInc = 'Whatever'
            profitInc = 0
            priceEnt = qEnt/2
            profitEnt = qEnt/4
        elif qEnt<qInc:
            priceInc = ((qInc-qEnt)*qInc)/(2*qInc-qEnt)
            profitInc = ((qEnt - qInc)*qInc)/(2*(qEnt - 2*qInc))
            priceEnt = ((qInc-qEnt)*qEnt)/(2*(2*qInc-qEnt))
            profitEnt = (qEnt*qInc*(-qEnt + qInc))/(4*(qEnt - 2*qInc)**2)
    elif Leader == 'Entrant':
        #The New Entrant is the leader in pricing
        if qEnt>qInc:
            priceInc = ((qInc-qEnt)*qInc)/(2*(qInc-2*qEnt))
            profitInc = (qEnt*qInc*(qEnt-qInc))/(4*((2*qEnt-qInc)**2))
            priceEnt = ((qInc-qEnt)*qEnt)/(qInc-2*qEnt)
            profitEnt = ((qEnt - qInc)*qEnt)/(4*qEnt - 2*qInc)
        elif qEnt==qInc:
            priceInc = qInc/2
            profitInc = qInc/4
            priceEnt = 'Whatever'
            profitEnt = 0
        elif qEnt<qInc:
            priceInc = ((qInc - qEnt)*(4*qInc - qEnt))/(4*(2*qInc - qEnt))
            profitInc = ((qInc - qEnt)*(-4*qInc + qEnt)**2)/(16*(-2*qInc + qEnt)**2)
            priceEnt = ((qInc - qEnt)*qEnt)/(2*(2*qInc - qEnt))
            profitEnt = ((qInc - qEnt)*qEnt)/(16*qInc - 8*qEnt)      
    return priceEnt,profitEnt,priceInc,profitInc

def KSpayoff(strategyEnt,strategyInc):
    global payoffEnt, payoffInc
    if strategyEnt=='S' and strategyInc=='S':
        payoffEnt=(1+Theta)*(r['Ent']+r['Inc']+Lambda*s+l['Ent'])-n['Ent']
        payoffInc=(1+Theta)*(r['Ent']+r['Inc']+(1-Lambda)*s+l['Inc'])-n['Inc']
    elif strategyEnt=='S' and strategyInc=='N':
        payoffEnt=(1+Theta)*(r['Ent']-n['Ent'])
        payoffInc=(1-Theta)*(r['Ent']+r['Inc']+v['Inc']+l['Inc'])
    elif strategyEnt=='N' and strategyInc=='S':
        payoffEnt=(1-Theta)*(r['Ent']+r['Inc']+v['Ent']+l['Ent'])
        payoffInc=(1+Theta)*(r['Inc']-n['Inc'])
    elif strategyEnt=='N' and strategyInc=='N':
        payoffEnt=(1-Theta)*(r['Ent']+v['Ent'])
        payoffInc=(1-Theta)*(r['Inc']+v['Inc'])
    return payoffEnt,payoffInc
def CApayoff(CAstrategyEnt,CAstrategyInc,KSstrategyEnt,KSstrategyInc,qEnt,qInc,Leader):
    global payoffEnt, payoffInc
    receivedknowledge = {}
    if KSstrategyEnt == 'N':
        receivedknowledge['Inc'] = 0
    else:
        receivedknowledge['Inc'] = 1 
    if KSstrategyInc == 'N':
        receivedknowledge['Ent'] = 0
    else:
        receivedknowledge['Ent'] = 1 
        
    if CAstrategyEnt=='R' and CAstrategyInc=='R':
        priceEnt,profitEnt,priceInc,profitInc = optimumprofitIncLead(qEnt,qInc,Leader)
        payoffEnt = rho['Ent']*profitEnt-c['Ent']['R']
        payoffInc = rho['Inc']*profitInc-c['Inc']['R']
    elif CAstrategyEnt=='R' and CAstrategyInc=='O':
        qInc += receivedknowledge['Inc']*k['Inc']+c['Inc']['O']/costToQualityRatio-phi['Inc']
        priceEnt,profitEnt,priceInc,profitInc = optimumprofitIncLead(qEnt,qInc,Leader)
        payoffEnt = rho['Ent']*profitEnt-c['Ent']['R']
        payoffInc = omega['Inc']*profitInc-c['Inc']['O']
    elif CAstrategyEnt=='R' and CAstrategyInc=='D':
        qInc += np.tanh(receivedknowledge['Inc']*k['Inc']+c['Inc']['D']/costToQualityRatio-tau['Inc'])
        priceEnt,profitEnt,priceInc,profitInc = optimumprofitIncLead(qEnt,qInc,Leader)
        payoffEnt = rho['Ent']*profitEnt-c['Ent']['R']
        payoffInc = delta['Inc']*profitInc-c['Inc']['D']
    elif CAstrategyEnt=='O' and CAstrategyInc=='R':
        qEnt += receivedknowledge['Ent']*k['Ent']+c['Ent']['O']/costToQualityRatio-phi['Ent']
        priceEnt,profitEnt,priceInc,profitInc = optimumprofitIncLead(qEnt,qInc,Leader)
        payoffEnt = omega['Ent']*profitEnt-c['Ent']['O']
        payoffInc = rho['Inc']*profitInc-c['Inc']['R']
    elif CAstrategyEnt=='O' and CAstrategyInc=='O':
        qEnt += receivedknowledge['Ent']*k['Ent']+c['Ent']['O']/costToQualityRatio-phi['Ent']
        qInc += receivedknowledge['Inc']*k['Inc']+c['Inc']['O']/costToQualityRatio-phi['Inc']
        priceEnt,profitEnt,priceInc,profitInc = optimumprofitIncLead(qEnt,qInc,Leader)
        payoffEnt = omega['Ent']*profitEnt-c['Ent']['O']
        payoffInc = omega['Inc']*profitInc-c['Inc']['O']
    elif CAstrategyEnt=='O' and CAstrategyInc=='D':
        qEnt += receivedknowledge['Ent']*k['Ent']+c['Ent']['O']/costToQualityRatio-phi['Ent']
        qInc += np.tanh(receivedknowledge['Inc']*k['Inc']+c['Inc']['D']/costToQualityRatio-tau['Inc'])
        priceEnt,profitEnt,priceInc,profitInc = optimumprofitIncLead(qEnt,qInc,Leader)
        payoffEnt = omega['Ent']*profitEnt-c['Ent']['O']
        payoffInc = delta['Inc']*profitInc-c['Inc']['D']
    elif CAstrategyEnt=='D' and CAstrategyInc=='R':
        qEnt += np.tanh(receivedknowledge['Ent']*k['Ent']+c['Ent']['D']/costToQualityRatio-tau['Ent'])
        priceEnt,profitEnt,priceInc,profitInc = optimumprofitIncLead(qEnt,qInc,Leader)
        payoffEnt = delta['Ent']*profitEnt-c['Ent']['D']
        payoffInc = rho['Inc']*profitInc-c['Inc']['R']
    elif CAstrategyEnt=='D' and CAstrategyInc=='O':
        qEnt += np.tanh(receivedknowledge['Ent']*k['Ent']+c['Ent']['D']/costToQualityRatio-tau['Ent'])
        qInc += receivedknowledge['Inc']*k['Inc']+c['Inc']['O']/costToQualityRatio-phi['Inc']
        priceEnt,profitEnt,priceInc,profitInc = optimumprofitIncLead(qEnt,qInc,Leader)
        payoffEnt = delta['Ent']*profitEnt-c['Ent']['D']
        payoffInc = omega['Inc']*profitInc-c['Inc']['O']
    elif CAstrategyEnt=='D' and CAstrategyInc=='D':
        qEnt += np.tanh(receivedknowledge['Ent']*k['Ent']+c['Ent']['D']/costToQualityRatio-tau['Ent'])
        qInc += np.tanh(receivedknowledge['Inc']*k['Inc']+c['Inc']['D']/costToQualityRatio-tau['Inc'])
        priceEnt,profitEnt,priceInc,profitInc = optimumprofitIncLead(qEnt,qInc,Leader)
        payoffEnt = delta['Ent']*profitEnt-c['Ent']['D']
        payoffInc = delta['Inc']*profitInc-c['Inc']['D']
    return payoffEnt,payoffInc,qEnt,qInc



\end{lstlisting}
```

There are three problems in the output (please also see the images):

1. Some Persian parts of the file which were OK before adding the python styling are now displayed in squares!!!

[image]

2. The coloring python code itself is fine, but all the words are displayed in reverse as can be seen in the image. For example the word `def` is displayed like `fed` which is weird.

[image]

3. The numbers are displayed in Persian. This is OK for the rest of the document but here I wish they could be in English.

Would be grateful for any advice. Thanks.

Comment: you should not load code meant for pdflatex like `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in a xepersian document. But beside this: your thesis class is not on ctan and so it is not possible to compile your code.

Comment: I found a solution for the last two problems. I just had to put the lisings inside \begin{latin}\end{latin}. But still problem 1 remains (squares).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried your suggestion and removed `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and also `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[english]{babel}`. And now everythin is back to normal. Thanks a lot.