# Using listings to add colorful code

Tags: listings

By default listings adds black and white code. How can I make them colorful. Language I work on are -> Python, Mathematica, IDL.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Have a look at [How to highlight Python syntax in LaTeX Listings \lstinputlistings command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83882/how-to-highlight-python-syntax-in-latex-listings-lstinputlistings-command), does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it is resolved. Use the following code to add color to comment, keyword, and strings of your script. I used for IDL, you can change the language and the color preference according to your style.

```
\lstset{language=IDL,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{magenta}\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
    morecomment=[1][\color{pink}]}{\#}
\lstinputlisting{codecurrentfree.pro}
```