# How to number the listings within sections?

Tags: listings, chngcntr

I use this excellent approach for inserting external Python code in my document.
[How to highlight Python syntax in LaTeX Listings \lstinputlistings command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83882/how-to-highlight-python-syntax-in-latex-listings-lstinputlistings-command/83883#83883)

```
\section{TEST}
\pythonexternal[caption=test, label=lst.test.py]{test.py}
```

But how can I number the listing in my document?

I have tried:

```
\uespackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}
```

The result: "! Package chngcntr Error: lstlisting is not a counter."

Comment: lstlisting - I have tried lstlistings, listing... nothing solved this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [listings](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) package delays the definition of the `lstlisting` counter until the `AtBeginDocument` phase. (See lines 1567 to 1576 in the file `listings.sty` for the complete details.) Hence, the `\counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}` instruction has to be wrapped in an `\AtBeginDocument` instruction in order to be successful.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,chngcntr}
\AtBeginDocument{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3} % just for this example
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Hello World}]
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :) \AtBeginDocument{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}} solved my problem - thank you :)