# How to put a list of code in appendix?

Tags: listings, code, appendix

I want to put a code in my thesis appendix.

[image: p]

```
print('This sentence is output to the screen')
# Output: This sentence is output to the screen

a = 5

print('The value of a is', a)
# Output: The value of a is 5
```

I heard of using:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
```

Comment: Please show what you already tried using the `lstlistings` environment. What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: @leandriis, thanks. I mean is there any other beside `lstlisting`?

Comment: An alternative might also be the `minted` package.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest method to insert a code you wrote in another file is using `lstinputlisting`. It requires `\usepackage{listings}`.

```
% firstline = 1, lastline = 10, firstnumber = 1, nolol, 
\lstinputlisting[label = {alg:file_name}, caption = {Legend}]
{file_name.extension}
```

`label` and `caption` are optional. The `extension` is mandatory. `nolol` means *no list of listings*, it should be used when you show sections of the code while explaining something about it, but don't actually insert the whole object.

The commented option changes the `firstline` and the `lastline` of the code to insert and you may also start the numbering at the `firstnumber`.

To insert a list of listings (*codes*, *algorithms*, *whatever*) use:

```
\lstlistoflistings
```

And if you need to rename title and captions use:

```
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Caption listings name}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of Codes renamed}
```

If you want to format the style I would suggest the following link:
[How to highlight Python syntax in LaTeX Listings \lstinputlistings command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83883/140133)
.

And more advices about `listings` in [LaTeX/Source Code Listings](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings).

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of packages to format source code. I use `listings` (flexible enough for my limited needs), others swear by pygments (a Python based source code formatter, can also write out LaTeX; PygmenTEX is a package for calling it from LaTeX).