# How to Integrate R code in TeXStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am writing my thesis in TeXStudio. One chapter features plots / analysis etc. that I am writing in a markdown in RStudio.

Is there a way to kinda "link" the documents so the output from R is displayed in my TeXStudio document and updated automatically in case I change my code in R?

best wishes (:

Comment: Hi @rabatz and welcome to TeX-SE. Please verify this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529346/140133) for python. The command `lstinputlisting` should work for R too. You should only find some method to apply the desire style you want. For example, there is `mcode` for Matlab syntax and the link I sent there is a style for python.

Comment: @FHZ I am afraid that the question is about show the R output (generated plots, tables, verbatim text results, etc.) rather that just show the R code.

Comment: Your life will be easier if you (1) rename your thesis.tex as tesis.Rnw and (2) inserting here the R chunks using the syntax <<chunkname, options>>= ... @ instead of \`\`\`{r....} ... `\`\` Or alternatively: (1) convert thesis.tex to thesis.Rmd and then just (2) insert your chapter Rmd in thesis.Rmd. In both cases (3) using only Rstudio to compile the whole thesis.

Comment: For textual output you can use: https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/rterface/rterface.pdf . // There is no embedded linking to my knowledge, as we know it from MS-Office or from web-server. Update is done when you compile the Latex document.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you just have to **save the plots as pictures** (.png, .jpg etc.) in your LaTeX figures folder and open them as usual. You can also specify in LaTeX any other folder on your computer by giving the full path.

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{F:/User/Thesis/R_Project/figures/example.PNG}
\caption[Title of Figure]{Actual Caption. It's nice if you understand the fig. by just reading this caption.}
\label{fig:res_r_lable}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: if it is really only a matter of having the plots added, I would suggest saving them as .pdf instead