# How to include a caption to a Python code snippet

Tags: listings, code

I am using a self-defined command to create an environment for my Python code that I want to show in my document. This command has been taken from redmode's answer to the following question: [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83882/how-to-highlight-python-syntax-in-latex-listings-lstinputlistings-command).

So, I am wondering: Is there a way to include a caption or subcaption to this code snippet then? The lstlisting environment allows for this option and I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Plesae always post code others can copy and test. If the self defined env (which you don't show) is made like in that example, then then `\begin{python}[caption={text}]` should work

Comment: right. Thx a lot, daleif! ... I didn't show the code since I litterally just copied and pasted from the linked answer.

Comment: Links can rot over time.  So it is always better to show the code, perhaps mention where it is from, but always show the code.