# UTF-8 Mu won't render inside custom environment

Tags: math-mode, environments, input-encodings, syntax-highlighting

I just tried using this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83883/143861 for syntax highlighting Python in overleaf

> ```
> \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
> \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
>
> % Default fixed font does not support bold face
> \DeclareFixedFont{\ttb}{T1}{txtt}{bx}{n}{12} % for bold
> \DeclareFixedFont{\ttm}{T1}{txtt}{m}{n}{12}  % for normal
>
> % Custom colors
> \usepackage{color}
> \definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
> \definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
> \definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
>
> \usepackage{listings}
>
> % Python style for highlighting
> \newcommand\pythonstyle{\lstset{
> language=Python,
> basicstyle=\ttm,
> morekeywords={self},              % Add keywords here
> keywordstyle=\ttb\color{deepblue},
> emph={MyClass,__init__},          % Custom highlighting
> emphstyle=\ttb\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
> stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
> frame=tb,                         % Any extra options here
> showstringspaces=false
> }}
>
>
> % Python environment
> \lstnewenvironment{python}[1][]
> {
> \pythonstyle
> \lstset{#1}
> }
> {}
>
> % Python for external files
> \newcommand\pythonexternal[2][]{{
> \pythonstyle
> \lstinputlisting[#1]{#2}}}
>
> % Python for inline
> \newcommand\pythoninline[1]{{\pythonstyle\lstinline!#1!}}
> ```

A Mu µ in the Python environment won't render

```tex
\begin{document}
\begin{python}
µ = 5
\end{python}
\end{document}
```

Due to this error:

> Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "B5.

It renders outside of the python environment.

How can I render a mu inside of a syntax-highlighted Python code block?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24528/having-problems-with-listings-and-utf-8-can-it-be-fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare the character to `listings`.

I suggest also to use `newtxtt` that has better symbol coverage than `txtt`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newtxtt}

% Custom colors
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}

\usepackage{listings}

% Python style for highlighting
\newcommand\pythonstyle{%
  \lstset{
    language=Python,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    morekeywords={self},              % Add keywords here
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{deepblue},
    emph={MyClass,__init__},          % Custom highlighting
    emphstyle=\bfseries\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
    stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
    frame=tb,                         % Any extra options here
    showstringspaces=false,
  }%
}

\lstset{literate={µ}{\textmu}{1}}


% Python environment
\lstnewenvironment{python}[1][]
  {\pythonstyle\lstset{#1}}
  {}

% Python for external files
\newcommand\pythonexternal[2][]{{%
  \pythonstyle
  \lstinputlisting[#1]{#2}%
}}

% Python for inline
\newcommand\pythoninline[1]{{\pythonstyle\lstinline!#1!}}

\begin{document}
\begin{python}
µ = 5
for f
\end{python}
\end{document}
```

The picture shows that there is a distinctive bold font.

[image]

Comment: How can you caption `\begin{python}` environments?

Comment: @theonlygusti `\begin{python}[caption={The caption text}]`?

Comment: I asked a new question about it https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/590342/143861