# Modifying existing Latex code to put Python codes in the Cheatsheet

Tags: color, templates, code, python

I want to make a cheatsheet for Pandas which has Python codes. I googled and tried to find a free online site that help to get built easily. I'm unable to find except overleaf which uses Latex codes to build pages.

I found a free cheatsheet template but I want to put my Python codes in this cheathseet with colors, i.e., for comments, keywords etc. I tried many way to modify the template's Latex code to get desired results. But no luck yet.

I tried with verbatim and lstlisting etc. But these gives some error so page not displays.

I'm using this 3-column cheatsheet:

[image]

> Can you please help to modify [this cheatsheet](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/python-cheat-sheet/kxzvswnbgqrx) latex'code so that I can put my Python code with colors in this cheatsheet ?

---

**Edit:**

As this code works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{python}
# Install Pandas
pip install pandas

# Import Pandas
import pandas as pd
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I want to add code in my code which is [document class code]:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Python Cheat Sheet
% baposter Landscape Poster
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (11/06/13)
% baposter Class Created by:
% Brian Amberg (baposter@brian-amberg.de)
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
% Edited by Michelle Cristina de Sousa Baltazar
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[landscape,a0paper,fontscale=0.285]{baposter} % Adjust the font scale/size here
\title{Pandas Cheat Sheet New}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
\graphicspath{{figures/}} % Directory in which figures are stored

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabu}


% Added by me
\usepackage{pythonhighlight}

% ________________________


\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{amsmath} % For typesetting math
\usepackage{amssymb} % Adds new symbols to be used in math mode

\usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for tables
\usepackage{enumitem} % Used to reduce itemize/enumerate spacing
\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} % Required for specifying captions to tables and figures

\usepackage{multicol} % Required for multiple columns
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em} % Slightly increase the space between columns
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm} % No horizontal rule between columns

\usepackage{tikz} % Required for flow chart
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows} % Tikz libraries required for the flow chart in the template

\newcommand{\compresslist}{ % Define a command to reduce spacing within itemize/enumerate environments, this is used right after \begin{itemize} or \begin{enumerate}
\setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}

\definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.145,0.6666,1} % Defines the color used for content box headers




\begin{document}

\begin{poster}
{
headerborder=closed, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
colspacing=0.8em, % Column spacing
bgColorOne=white, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster
bgColorTwo=white, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster
borderColor=lightblue, % Border color
headerColorOne=black, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
headerColorTwo=lightblue, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
boxColorOne=white, % Background color of the content boxes
textborder=roundedleft, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
eyecatcher=true, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left
headerheight=0.1\textheight, % Height of the header
headershape=roundedright, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes
%textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation
linewidth=2pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------
%   TÍTULO
%----------------------------------------------------------------
{\bf\textsc{Pandas Cheat Sheet}\vspace{0.5em}} % Poster title
{\textsc{\{ P a n d a s \ \ \ \ \ C h e a t \ \ \ \ \ S h e e t\} \hspace{12pt}}}
{\textsc{Basic Cheat sheet for Pandas Library \\ (By Guru99) \hspace{12pt}}} 


%------------------------------------------------
% BÁSICO DO PYTHON
%------------------------------------------------
\headerbox{About Pandas:}{name=objectives,column=0,row=0}{

%--------------------------------------
\colorbox[HTML]{CCFFFF}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\bf - Intro:}}
\begin{itemize}\compresslist
\item Pandas is a Python open-source library used for working with data sets.
\item It is free to use and easy to learn.
\item Pandas has functions for analyzing, cleaning, exploring, and manipulating data.
\item It was created by Wes McKinney in 2008.
\item Pandas is built on top of Numpy.
\end{itemize}


%--------------------------------------
\colorbox[HTML]{CCFFFF}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\bf - About this Pandas Cheat Sheet:}} 
\begin{itemize}\compresslist
\item There are various functions in the Pandas library.
\item Cheat sheets cover many topics. 
\item You can work with Series and DataFrame types of data structure.
\item In short, the Panda Cheat Sheet is a great resource for anyone.
\item Anyone who wants to learn more about using Python for Data Science!
\end{itemize}
\dotfill \newline

%--------------------------------------
\colorbox[HTML]{CCFFFF}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\bf - To Start: Install and Import:}}
%\begin{tabular}{lp{2.0cm}lp{3.0cm}|}

%------NÚMEROS ALEATÓRIOS----------
% \colorbox[HTML]{CCFFFF}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\bf - Números Aleatórios}}
To start working with pandas functions you need to install and import pandas. There are two commands to do this:
\newline

\pyth{# Install Pandas}\newline
\pyth{pip install pandas}\newline

\pyth{# Import Pandas}\newline
\pyth{import pandas as pd}\newline

\colorbox[HTML]{CCFFFF}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\bf - To Start: Install and Import:}}
Strings são compostos de caracteres: \\ 
uma\_string = "Hello World!" \\
outra\_string = 'Ola Mundo!"

Strings são compostos de caracteres: \\ 
uma\_string = "Hello World!" \\
outra\_string = 'Ola Mundo!"


% \begin{tabular}{lp{5.3cm}lp{3.0cm}|}
% A = input() & Aguarda a entrada de caracteres armazenados em A \\
% \end{tabular}
% \begin{tabular}{lp{4.7cm}lp{3.0cm}|}
% B = int(input()) & Aguarda a entrada de inteiros armazenados em B \\
% \end{tabular}
% \begin{tabular}{lp{2.6cm}lp{3.0cm}|}
% A,B = map(int,input().split()) & Aguarda a entrada de inteiros  separados por espaço, armazenados em A e B respectivamente \\
% \end{tabular}
% \begin{tabular}{lp{3.0cm}lp{3.0cm}|}
% input("Pressione ENTER") & Aguarda pressionar ENTER para prosseguir - como não declarou nenhuma variável, não irá gravar nada. \\
% \end{tabular}

\vspace{0.0em} % When there are two boxes, some whitespace may need to be added if the one on the right has more content


}

%------------------------------------------------
% Lógica Básica do Python
%------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Lógica Básica do Python}{name=introduction,column=1,row=0,bottomaligned=objectives}{

%------IF--------
\colorbox[HTML]{CCFFFF}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\bf - if}}
\begin{itemize}\compresslist
\item if teste:\\
........\# faça algo se teste der verdadeiro\\
elif teste2\\
........\# faça algo se teste2 der verdadeiro\\
else:\newline
........\# faça algo se ambos derem falso
\end{itemize}


%------WHILE--------
\colorbox[HTML]{CCFFFF}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\bf - while:}}
\begin{itemize}\compresslist
\item while teste:\\
........\# enquanto verdadeiro continue fazendo algo
\end{itemize}


%------FOR--------
\colorbox[HTML]{CCFFFF}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\bf - for:}}
\begin{itemize}\compresslist
\item for x in sequência\\
........\# enquanto o x estiver na sequência informada\\
........\# faça algo para cada item na sequência\\
........\# a sequência pode ser uma lista,\\
........\# elementos de uma string, etc.

\item for x in range(10)\\
........\# repita algo 10 vezes (de 0 a 9)

\item for x in range(5,10)\\
........\# repita algo 5 vezes (de 5 a 9)
\end{itemize}

\colorbox[HTML]{CCFFFF}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\bf - Testes Lógicos}}
\linebreak \\
\begin{tabular}{l l}
10 == 10 & retorna: True \\
10 == 11 & retorna: False \\
10!= 11 & retorna: True \\
"jack" == "jack" & retorna: True \\
"jack" == "jake" & retorna: False \\
10 > 10 & retorna: False \\
10 >= 10 & retorna: True \\
"abc" >= "abc" & retorna: True \\
"abc" < "abc" & retorna: False \\
\end{tabular}
}


%------------------------------------------------
% Listas no Python
%------------------------------------------------

\headerbox{Listas no Python}{name=results,column=2,span=2,row=0}{

\colorbox[HTML]{CCFFFF}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\bf - Listas no Python}}
\linebreak \\
Listas são compostas por elementos de qualquer tipo (podem ser alteradas) \linebreak \\
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\textbf{Manipulação de Listas no Python}\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDFFFF}Criação} \\
uma\_lista = [5,3,'p',9,'e'] & cria: [5,3,'p',9,'e'] \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDFFFF}Acessando} \\
uma\_lista[0] & retorna: 5 \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDFFFF}Fatiando} \\
uma\_lista[1:3] & retorna: [3,'p'] \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDFFFF}Comprimento} \\
len(uma\_lista) & retorna: 5 \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDFFFF}count( item)} \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Retorna quantas vezes o item foi encontrado na lista.} \\
cont(uma\_lista('p') & retorna: 1 \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Pode ser usado juntamente com a função while para 'andar' pelo comprimento da lista:} \\
while x < len(uma\_lista): & retorna: [3,'p']\\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDFFFF}Ordenar - sort()} \\
uma\_lista.sort() & retorna: [3,5,9,'e','p'] \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Ordenar sem alterar a lista} \\
print(sorted(uma\_lista)) & retorna: [3,5,9,'e','p'] \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDFFFF}Adicionar - append(item)} \\
uma\_lista.append(37) & retorna: [5,3,'p',9,'e',37] \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDFFFF}Inserir - insert(position,item)} \\
insert(uma\_lista.append(3),200) & retorna: [5,3,200,'p',9,'e'] \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDFFFF}Retornar e remover - pop(position)} \\
uma\_lista.pop() & retorna: 'e' e a lista fica [5,3,'p',9] - remove o último elemento \\
uma\_lista.pop(1) & retorna: 3 e a lista fica [5,'p',9,'e'] - remove o elemento 1 \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDFFFF}Remover - remove(item)} \\
uma\_lista.remove('p') & retorna: [5,3,9,'e'] \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDFFFF}Inserir} \\
uma\_lista.insert(2,'z') & retorna: [5,'z',3,'p',9,'e'] - insere na posição numerada \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDFFFF}Inverter - reverse()} \\
reverse(uma\_lista) & retorna: ['e',9,'p',3,5] \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDFFFF}Concatenar} \\
uma\_lista+[0] & retorna: [5,3,'p',9,'e',0] \\
uma\_lista+uma\_lista & retorna: [5,3,'p',9,'e',5,3,'p',9,'e'] \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDFFFF}Encontrar} \\
9 in uma\_lista & retorna: True \\
for x in uma\_lista & retorna toda a lista, um elemento por linha \\
......print(x) &  
\end{tabular}
%------------------------------------------------
}
\end{poster}
\newpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    SEGUNDA PÁGINA    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{poster}
{
headerborder=closed, colspacing=0.8em, bgColorOne=white, bgColorTwo=white, borderColor=lightblue, headerColorOne=black, headerColorTwo=lightblue, 
headerFontColor=white, boxColorOne=white, textborder=roundedleft, eyecatcher=true, headerheight=0.1\textheight, headershape=roundedright, headerfont=\Large\bf\textsc, linewidth=2pt 
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION 
%----------------------------------------------------------------
{\bf\textsc{Python Cheat Sheet}\vspace{0.5em}} % Poster title
{\textsc{\{ P y t h o n \ \ \ \ \ C h e a t \ \ \ \ \ S h e e t\} \hspace{12pt}}}
{\textsc{Michelle Cristina de Sousa Baltazar \\ (Universidade Federal do Triângulo Mineiro) \hspace{12pt}}} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------
%   Outros Elementos
%----------------------------------------------------------------
\headerbox{Outros Elementos}{name=method,column=0}{

\colorbox[HTML]{CCFFFF}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\bf - Palavras-Chave}}
\begin{tabular}{lp{5.8cm}lp{1.0cm}}
{\bf Oper.} & {\bf Descrição}\\
print & Imprime para a tela \\
while & "Enquanto" - laço para repetição de alguma condição \\
for & "Para" - loop para repetição de alguma condição \\
break & Interrompe o loop caso necessário \\
continue & Interrompe o loop atual sem sair do loop, reiniciando \\
if & "Se" - usado para testar alguma condição \\
elif & É uma variante para o "senão" - se a primeira condição falha, testa a próxima \\
else & "Senão" - é opicional e será executado quando a primeira condição falhar \\
is & Testa a identidade do objeto \\
import & Importa outros módulos para dentro de um script \\
as & Usado para dar um apelido (alias) para um módulo \\
from & Para importar uma variável especifica, classe ou função de um módulo \\
def & Usado para criar uma função nova definida pelo usuário \\
return & Sai da função e retorna um valor \\
lambda & Cria uma função nova anônima \\
global & Acessa variáveis definida globalmente (fora de uma função) \\
try & Especifica manipuladores de exceções  \\
except & Captura a exceção e executa códigos \\
finally & É sempre executado no final, utilizado para limpar os recursos \\
raise & Cria uma exceção definida pelo usuário \\
del & Deleta objetos \\
pass & Não faz nada \\
assert & Usado para fins de depuração \\
class & Usado para criar objetos definidos pelo usuário \\
exec & Executa dinamicamente um código Python \\
yield & É usado com geradores
\end{tabular}


}

%----------------------------------------------------------------
%   Operadores
%----------------------------------------------------------------
\headerbox{Operadores Python}{name=results2,column=1}{
Tomemos como exemplo a=10 e b=20:\\
\colorbox[HTML]{CCFFFF}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\bf - Operadores Aritméticos}}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
{\bf Op.} & {\bf Descrição} & {\bf Exemplo} \\
+ & Adição & a + b retorna: 30 \\
- & Subtração & a - b retorna: -10 \\
* & Multiplicação & a * b retorna: 200 \\
/ & Divisão & b / a retorna: 2 \\
\% & Módulo & a \% b retorna: 0 \\
** & Exponencial & a**b retorna: $10^{20}$ \\
// & Divisão Piso & 9 // 2 retorna: 4
\end{tabular}

%----OPERADORES DE COMPARAÇÃO-----------
\colorbox[HTML]{CCFFFF}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\bf - Operadores de Comparação}}
As operações básicas de comparação podem ser usadas de diversas maneiras para todos os tipos de valores - números, strings, sequencias, listas, etc. O retorno será sempre True ou False.\\
\begin{tabular}{lll}
{\bf Op.} & {\bf Descrição} & {\bf Exemplo} \\
< & Menor que & a < b retorna: True \\
<= & Menor ou igual & a <= b retorna: True \\
== & Igual & a == b retorna: False \\
> & Maior que & a > b retorna: False \\
>= & Maior ou igual & a >= b retorna: False \\
!= & Diferente & a != b retorna: True \\
<> & Diferente & a <> b retorna: True
\end{tabular}

%------OPERADORES LÓGICOS-----------
\colorbox[HTML]{CCFFFF}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\bf - Operadores Lógicos}}
Os operadores lógicos {\bf and} e {\bf or} Também retornam um valor booleano quando usado em uma estrutura de decisão.\\
\begin{tabular}{lp{6.5cm}lp{1.0cm}|}
{\bf Op.} & {\bf Descrição}\\
and & Se o resultado de ambos operadores é verdadeiro, retorna: True \\
or & Se um dos resultados retorna verdadeiro, retorna: True \\
not & É utilizado para reverter o estado lógico de qualquer operação booleana.
\end{tabular}

%-------TUPLAS---------------------
\colorbox[HTML]{CCFFFF}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\bf - Tuplas no Python}}
Tupla é uma lista de valores separados por vírgulas - é similar à uma lista porém é imutável: \\ 
uma\_tupla = 'a','b','c','d','e' \\
outra\_tupla = ('a','b','c','d','e') \\

%------NÚMEROS ALEATÓRIOS----------
\colorbox[HTML]{CCFFFF}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\bf - Números Aleatórios}}
Strings são compostos de caracteres: \\ 
uma\_string = "Hello World!" \\
outra\_string = 'Ola Mundo!"

}

%----------------------------------------------------------------
%   Strings no Python
%----------------------------------------------------------------
\headerbox{Strings no Python}{name=conclusion,column=2,span=2,row=0}{
string é uma sequencia de caracteres geralmente usada para armazenar texto. \\
Strings são compostos de caracteres (não podem ser alterados - são imutáveis) \\ 
\linebreak
%% {lp{5.8cm}lp{1.0cm}|}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lp{10.2cm}l@{}}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDFFFF}Criação} \\
uma\_string = "Hello World!" & outra\_string = 'Ola Mundo!" \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDFFFF}Acessando} \\
uma\_string[4] & retorna: 'o' \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{(este caso retorna a 4ª posição do texto - começando a contar a partir do zero)} \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDFFFF}Dividindo} \\
uma\_string.split('') & retorna ['Hello','World'] \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{(este caso divide o texto no espaço em branco em uma lista de duas strings)} \\
uma\_string.split('r') & retorna ['Hello Wo','ld'] \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{(este caso divide o texto na letra 'r' em uma lista de duas strings)} \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDFFFF}Unindo} \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Para unir uma lista de strings usaremos a função join() } \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{uma\_lista = ["isto","eh","uma","lista","de","strings"]} \\
' '.join(uma\_lista) & retorna: "isto eh uma lista de strings" \\
' 'TESTE'.join(uma\_lista) & Retorna: \\
''.join(uma\_lista) & retorna: "istoehumalistadestrings" \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor[HTML]{DDFFFF}Formatando Strings} \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Podemos usar o operador \% para adicionar elementos em uma string:} \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{esta\_string = "todos"} \\
print("Olá para \%s!" \%esta\_string) & retorna: "Olá para todos!" \\
\end{tabular}
\linebreak

%-----OPERAÇÕES COM STRINGS----------
\colorbox[HTML]{CCFFFF}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\bf - Operações com Strings}}
Definindo as variaveis de string para exemplo da seguinte forma: a = ['Hello'] e b = ['Python'] \\
\begin{tabular}{lp{9.0cm}lp{1.0cm}lp{1.0cm}} %\begin{tabular}{lll}
{\bf Oper.} & {\bf Descrição} & {\bf Exemplo} \\
+ & Concatenation - soma o conteúdo das duas strings & a + b retorna: HelloPython \\
* & Repetition - repete o conteúdo da string N vezes & a*2 retorna: HelloHello \\
.[ ] & Slice - fatia retornando o caractere no respectivo indice & a[1] retorna: "e" \\
.[ : ] & Range Slice - retorna os caracteres do intervalo indicado & a[1:4] retorna: "ell" \\
in & Membership - se o caractere existe na string, retorna true & H in a will give 1 \\
not in & Membership - se o caractere não existe na string, retorna true & M not in a retorna: 1 \\
\% & Format - formata uma string & exemplos na tabela seguinte \\
\end{tabular}

%------FORMATAÇÃO DE STRINGS---------
\colorbox[HTML]{CCFFFF}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\bf - Formatação de Strings}}
\begin{tabular}{ll|ll} %\begin{tabular}{lp{3.0cm}lp{4.0cm}lp{2.0cm}lp{2.0cm}|} 
{\bf Símbolo} & {\bf Conversão} & {\bf Símbolo} & {\bf Conversão} \\
\%c & caractere                 & \%i & decimal inteiro com sinal \\
\%d & decimal inteiro com sinal & \%u & decimal inteiro sem sinal \\
\%o & octal inteiro             & \%x & hexadecimal inteiro (letras minúsculas) \\
\%f & numero real ponto flutuante & \%X & hexadecimal inteiro (letras maiúsculas) \\
\%g & o menor entre \%f e \%e & \%e & notação exponencial (com 'e' minúsculo) \\
\%G & o menor entre \%f e \%E & \%E & notação exponencial (com 'E' maiúsculo) \\
. & . & \%s & converção de string via str() antes de formatar \\
\end{tabular}

%-----------------------------------
}
%----------------------------------------------------------------
%   REFERENCES  {name=objectives,column=0,row=0}
%----------------------------------------------------------------
%\headerbox{bb}{name=references,column=1,row=0}{}
%----------------------------------------------------------------
%   FUTURE RESEARCH
%----------------------------------------------------------------
%\headerbox{aa}{name=futureresearch,column=1,row=0}{}
%----------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------
%\headerbox{Contact Information}{name=contact,column=2,span=2,row=0}{}
%----------------------------------------------------------------
\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

I want insert Python, for example - in the section : To Start: Install and Import:

```
# Install Pandas
pip install pandas

# Import Pandas
import pandas as pd
```

I want to show this python code colorfull as given in earlier screenshot. I tried to `\usepackage{minted}` before `\begin{document}` then tried to use `\begin{document}` with closing tag.
But it shows me blank page instead of showing anything.

Further (after solving above easy one) I would like to use this code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{xcolor}

%New colors defined below
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

%Code listing style named "mystyle"
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
  backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour}, commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
  keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
  stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  breakatwhitespace=false,         
  breaklines=true,                 
  captionpos=b,                    
  keepspaces=true,                                  
  showspaces=false,                
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,                  
  tabsize=2
}

%"mystyle" code listing set
\lstset{style=mystyle}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
# Install Pandas
pip install pandas

# Import Pandas
import pandas as pd
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Which has preview:

[image]

But as I use 3-column cheatsheet, so this should be from left side and there should not be wastage of space.

---

I found `pyth{}` from [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83882/how-to-highlight-python-syntax-in-latex-listings-lstinputlistings-command#comment1195209_369489). I need to use it for every-line, but it takes more space, so it is not much helpful. I'm looking for better solution, which can be solve in the above codes.

---

I tried with `\usepackage{minted}` but it shows me blank page. So I removed it. Note that it is runing on overleaf simply if you just paste first above example with `minuted`, it will execute there. It is not runing with my case/code.

---

**Edit:**
I noticed that this is problem because of `baposter`.

This code works for second example with `listings`, but it became single-column instead of three columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \documentclass[landscape,a0paper,fontscale=0.285]{baposter} % Adjust the font scale/size here
```

And, this has three-column but does not work for `listings`:

```
% \documentclass{article}
\documentclass[landscape,a0paper,fontscale=0.285]{baposter} % Adjust the font scale/size here
```

> Now, I have separe code file for `baposter.cls`. What could be possible solution regarding this ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Most people on this site aren't likely to follow a link and start wading through an Overleaf project.  Could you trim your code down to a minimal amount with Python and listings that you think should work but doesn't?

Comment: If you just want to list code, there are nice listing packages at ctan.org .

Comment: You’ll want to add a package that does listings, and wrap the code in an environment.

Comment: @Davislor , I tried to them, but they show blank page.

Comment: @Teepeemm , I've edited post accordingly.

Comment: Overleaf doesn't have basposter, so your example doesn't work. Please trim your example down to ~30 lines that has 3 columns and `\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]`.

Comment: `minted` requires `-shell-escape` settings to run and produce, it would be best to check the documentation on CTAN to see how to run it on Overleaf with shell escape

Comment: @JamesT Overleaf has shell-escape switched on by default.

Comment: @ close voters: the question is a bit of a mess but in essence it just asks how to use minted and/or listings in `baposter`, which is a clear and answerable question I think so I'll vote to leave open.